# What is the right way to embed the Zend Framework

Tags: 7

I'm currently looking for a way to embed the Zend framework into D7. I have found this module http://drupal.org/project/zend, but no matter what I try, I can't get to work.

It is said the 3.0 branch is for ZF2. So I enabled that module and I put the Zend folder (the one inside the framework libraries folder) in `/sites/libraries`. But in status report it keeps saying that the Zend Framework is not found.

I have no Drush on the server, but it should also be possible with plain FTP, right?

Also, sometimes when enabling the module (so other times this does not happen), the whole page comes served as plain text with an error at the bottom stating that mysql has disconnected.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Oh it's so interesting. I haven't known that we can use the Zend Framework library in Drupal. I downloaded that module and they said that you must use the curl to install. Did you try that?

Comment: No not yet. I read some things about drush... But I was hoping simply adding the folder to libraries would do the trick. Will give it try tomorrow.

Comment: It appeared I had to use version 1 of the framework for the module, so I downloaded the 7.0 beta module and it worked flawless with libraries API.

Comment: Oh. That's good. By the way. What led you to use Zend Framework in Drupal. Can't Drupal handle your requirements alone?

Comment: There are very few working picasa galleries for drupal 7. And the company has all of their photo's there. So I was looking for a stable system that can easilly be upgraded to Drupal 8 :)

Comment: Oh i see. You've planned to move Drupal 8. You're so innovative